# Get notified from avahi

Tags: shell-script, avahi

After looking for a zero-conf browser valid implementation I realised that inside my linux machine (ubuntu) I already have avahi and typing:

```
avahi-browse -alr
```

I get a complete list of all devices notified by their bonjour conf.

**Question:** how to get events from it? I mean, how can I get notification (execute a script) when a bonjour device is connecting on my network? How to detect when it is switched off?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, However there are some command combinations that will allow you to get a starting result. This can be achieved by Crontab or sleep (I'll use the latter).

1. write the results `avahi-browse -alr`
2. loop until killed (`while true`)
3. `sleep`(requested interval time)
4. write the results `avahi-browse -alr` to a temp file
5. use `diff` command to find differences between the new and old log, and `grep` the new lines (if there is a specific regex to them)
6. use the `mail` command to send your results or write them to a log file.